# Broken dependency in Golang Cloud packages

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-platform

I'm attempting to import "cloud.google.com/go/datastore" into my package but am recieveing the following error:

```
# github.com/AndyNortrup/baby-namer/vendor/google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/api/annotations

../vendor/google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/api/annotations/annotations.pb.go:41: unknown "github.com/AndyNortrup/baby-namer/vendor/github.com/golang/protobuf/proto".ExtensionDesc field 'Filename' in struct literal
```

The file `annotations.pb.go` has:

```
var E_Http = &proto.ExtensionDesc{
    ExtendedType:  (*google_protobuf.MethodOptions)(nil),
    ExtensionType: (*HttpRule)(nil),
    Field:         72295728,
    Name:          "google.api.http",
    Tag:           "bytes,72295728,opt,name=http",
    Filename:      "google/api/annotations.proto",
}
```

The file `/vendor/github.com/golang/protobuf/proto/extensions.go` doesn't include Filename:

```
// ExtensionDesc represents an extension specification.
// Used in generated code from the protocol compiler.
type ExtensionDesc struct {
    ExtendedType  Message     // nil pointer to the type that is being extended
    ExtensionType interface{} // nil pointer to the extension type
    Field         int32       // field number
    Name          string      // fully-qualified name of extension, for text formatting
    Tag           string      // protobuf tag style
}
```

I've pulled in all of the dependencies with govendor so I'm inclined to say that everything I have is everything I need.  But I can see in the file [here](https://github.com/golang/protobuf/blob/master/proto/extensions.go), that there are versions with the Filename attribute, so it appears I could substitue one for the other, but I'm not sure how to go about that.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you made any progress with this? I'm currently running into the same issue.

Comment: No progress, I switched back to using the appengine datastore packages.

Comment: Thanks. I wound up just removing all of my packages from /src and any others that had been built and re-fetched them and seemed to resolve my issue.